# Creating nested log entries in Cloud Logging Viewer from API?

Tags: google-cloud-logging

I'd like to publish logs from a custom app running on a compute engine to the cloud logging API.

However, I'd like to get nested logs (like AppEngine loglines). Is this possible through the api?

Answer (score 2):

This use-case is explained in the [AppEngline Logs docs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/service/appengine-logs#linking_application_logs_and_requests).

Make sure to also set the `traceId` fields to non-null values on the request and app logs which you are sending. Here's sample code in Scala:

```
import com.google.cloud.MonitoredResource
import com.google.cloud.logging.Payload._
import com.google.cloud.logging._
import collection.JavaConverters._
import org.threeten.bp.Duration

val logging = LoggingOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService()
val traceId = "keasdfwxcbrbntpoiuwehrtiojsadf";

var firstEntry = {
  LogEntry.newBuilder(StringPayload.of("string-payload-one"))
    .setSeverity(Severity.DEBUG)
    .setLogName("app")
    .setTimestamp(1519955138399L)
    .setResource(MonitoredResource.newBuilder("global").build())
    .setLabels(Map("environment" -> "testing").asJava)
    .setTrace(traceId)
    .build()
}

var midEntry = {
  LogEntry.newBuilder(StringPayload.of("string-payload-two"))
    .setSeverity(Severity.INFO)
    .setLogName("request")
    .setResource(MonitoredResource.newBuilder("global").build())
    .setHttpRequest(HttpRequest.newBuilder().setStatus(200).setRequestUrl("/about-us").setLatency(Duration.ofMillis(1234)).build())
    .setTimestamp(1519955137906L)
    .setLabels(Map("environment" -> "testing").asJava)
    .setTrace(traceId)
    .build()
}

var lastEntry = {
  LogEntry.newBuilder(StringPayload.of("string-payload-three"))
    .setSeverity(Severity.DEBUG)
    .setLogName("app")
    .setResource(MonitoredResource.newBuilder("global").build())
    .setTimestamp(1519955138523L)
    .setLabels(Map("environment" -> "testing").asJava)
    .setTrace(traceId)
    .build()
}

logging.write(List(firstEntry, midEntry, lastEntry).asJava)
```

At the end, the log entries should show up both in their individual logs and "cross-logged" as children of their requests, like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not documented as it should be (per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36921823/10728) circa 2016), but if you inspect a `LogEntry` from GAE, you should be able to reproduce it from elsewhere. Here's an example:

```
{
  "httpRequest": {
    "status": 500
  },
  "insertId": "5a93c0d800088625d8b7e45f",
  "labels": {
    "clone_id": "00c61b117c43aee4462ccf2cc75fa0a439d65d89992032719b9f34b7b4fa341bf0d3b7de"
  },
  "logName": "projects/matchmaker/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Frequest_log",
  "operation": {
    "id": "5a93be8000ff0e7e83cece7ced0001737e70726f6a656374736572656e6469700001323031373131323474313631353036000100",
    "last": true,
    "producer": "appengine.googleapis.com/request_id"
  },
  "protoPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.logging.v1.RequestLog",
    "appEngineRelease": "1.9.54",
    "appId": "s~matchmaker",
    "cost": 3.5092199999999997e-07,
    "endTime": "2018-02-26T08:10:00.558238Z",
    "finished": true,
    "host": "matchmaker.appspot.com",
    "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
    "instanceId": "00c61b117c43aee4462ccf2cc75fa0a439d65d89992032719b9f34b7b4fa341bf0d3b7de",
    "instanceIndex": -1,
    "ip": "0.1.0.1",
    "latency": "599.608347s",
    "line": [
      {
        "logMessage": "mail_body: Hi X and Y,<br>\n<br>\nYou've been matched!<br>\n<br>\nGo forth and one-on-one, and may it be as awesome as a peregrine falcon soaring\nthrough the rays of a setting sun.<br>\n<br>\nCheers,<br>\nProject Lemma<br>\n<br>\nPS: I'm not a calendar (yet) so it's up to you two to find a time to meet.",
        "severity": "INFO",
        "sourceLocation": {
          "file": "/base/data/home/apps/s~matchmaker/20171124t161506.405758693491065379/models/match.py",
          "functionName": "send_email_and_put",
          "line": "47"
        },
        "time": "2018-02-26T08:09:41.148490Z"
      },
      {
        "logMessage": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n   File \"/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/a7637d5531ec9deb_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py\", line 267, in Handle\n     result = handler(dict(self._environ), self._StartResponse)\n   File \"/base/data/home/apps/s~matchmaker/20171124t161506.405758693491065379/lib/flask/app.py\", line 2000, in __call__\n     return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)\n   File \"/base/data/home/apps/s~matchmaker/20171124t161506.405758693491065379/lib/flask/app.py\", line 1988, in wsgi_app\n     response = self.full_dispatch_request()\n   File \"/base/data/home/apps/s~matchmaker/20171124t161506.405758693491065379/lib/flask/app.py\", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request\n     rv = self.dispatch_request()\n   File \"/base/data/home/apps/s~matchmaker/20171124t161506.405758693491065379/lib/flask/app.py\", line 1625, in dispatch_request\n     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)\n   File \"/base/data/home/apps/s~matchmaker/20171124t161506.405758693491065379/cron/__init__.py\", line 11, in matches\n     for match in all_matches():\n   File \"/base/data/home/apps/s~matchmaker/20171124t161506.405758693491065379/cron/matches.py\", line 21, in all_matches\n     possibilities = {u.key: u.possible_matches for u in avail}\n   File \"/base/data/home/apps/s~matchmaker/20171124t161506.405758693491065379/cron/matches.py\", line 21, in <dictcomp>\n     possibilities = {u.key: u.possible_matches for u in avail}\n   File \"/base/data/home/apps/s~matchmaker/20171124t161506.405758693491065379/models/user.py\", line 64, in possible_matches\n     return sorted(matches, reverse=True)\n   File \"/base/data/home/apps/s~matchmaker/20171124t161506.405758693491065379/models/match.py\", line 19, in __cmp__\n     return cmp(self.score, other.score)\n   File \"/base/data/home/apps/s~matchmaker/20171124t161506.405758693491065379/models/match.py\", line 71, in score\n     total_capacity = sum(f.get().cur_capacity for f in self.folks)\n   File \"/base/data/home/apps/s~matchmaker/20171124t161506.405758693491065379/models/match.py\", line 71, in <genexpr>\n     total_capacity = sum(f.get().cur_capacity for f in self.folks)\n   File \"/base/data/home/apps/s~matchmaker/20171124t161506.405758693491065379/models/user.py\", line 33, in cur_capacity\n     return int(self.settings['freq']) - len(self.cur_matches)\n   File \"/base/data/home/apps/s~matchmaker/20171124t161506.405758693491065379/models/user.py\", line 47, in cur_matches\n     ).fetch(1000)\n   File \"/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/a7637d5531ec9deb_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/utils.py\", line 160, in positional_wrapper\n     return wrapped(*args, **kwds)\n   File \"/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/a7637d5531ec9deb_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/query.py\", line 1218, in fetch\n     return self.fetch_async(limit, **q_options).get_result()\n   File \"/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/a7637d5531ec9deb_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py\", line 383, in get_result\n     self.check_success()\n   File \"/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/a7637d5531ec9deb_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py\", line 378, in check_success\n     self.wait()\n   File \"/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/a7637d5531ec9deb_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py\", line 362, in wait\n     if not ev.run1():\n   File \"/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/a7637d5531ec9deb_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/eventloop.py\", line 268, in run1\n     delay = self.run0()\n   File \"/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/a7637d5531ec9deb_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/eventloop.py\", line 230, in run0\n     callback(*args, **kwds)\n   File \"/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/a7637d5531ec9deb_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py\", line 433, in _help_tasklet_along\n     ns = namespace_manager.get_namespace()\n   File \"/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/a7637d5531ec9deb_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/namespace_manager/namespace_manager.py\", line 86, in get_namespace\n     name = os.environ.get(_ENV_CURRENT_NAMESPACE, None)\n   File \"/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/a7637d5531ec9deb_unzipped/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.py\", line 382, in get\n     return self[key]\n   File \"/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/a7637d5531ec9deb_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/request_environment.py\", line 125, in __getitem__\n     def __getitem__(self, key):\n DeadlineExceededError: The overall deadline for responding to the HTTP request was exceeded.",
        "severity": "ERROR",
        "sourceLocation": {
          "file": "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/a7637d5531ec9deb_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py",
          "functionName": "Handle",
          "line": "279"
        },
        "time": "2018-02-26T08:10:00.549690Z"
      }
    ],
    "megaCycles": "34946",
    "method": "GET",
    "requestId": "5a93be8000ff0e7e83cece7ced0001737e70726f6a656374736572656e6469700001323031373131323474313631353036000100",
    "resource": "/cron/matches",
    "startTime": "2018-02-26T08:00:00.949891Z",
    "status": 500,
    "taskName": "f5915e6b03b632b41d45204c6686840b",
    "taskQueueName": "__cron",
    "urlMapEntry": "cron.APP",
    "userAgent": "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)",
    "versionId": "20171124t161506"
  },
  "receiveTimestamp": "2018-02-26T08:10:00.564188790Z",
  "resource": {
    "labels": {
      "module_id": "default",
      "project_id": "matchmaker",
      "version_id": "20171124t161506",
      "zone": "us2"
    },
    "type": "gae_app"
  },
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "timestamp": "2018-02-26T08:00:00.949891Z"
}
```

Comment: Please do not vandalize your own answer.

Comment: SO won't let me downvote it — it's the wrong direction, as far as I can tell. "line" is ignored regardless of what else I do, but the other answer I linked works — https://stackoverflow.com/a/49036936/10728

Comment: As you wish! padpadpad

Comment: You might be able to get your bounty back possibly. Although that bounty really confuses me.

Comment: I just really wanted the answer. It's still a bit confusing — the logs show up both nested and un-nested when I follow those directions. Getting it back would be nice, of course.

Comment: Well that bounty is only 4 times my total rep XD! Quote of the year - "Getting [500 rep] back would be nice"

Comment: Happy to give it to you if you want to comment with the link to the docs @GrantGarrison

Comment: Wait so you will give me 500 rep?

Comment: If you answer the question, yes. That’s how bounties work! >_<

Comment: The link itself is a good answer and I can extend it with code and and a screenshot.

Comment: It’s the other link but I’ll fix it in a min https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/service/appengine-logs#linking_application_logs_and_requests

Comment: Actually, I included some of the stuff from that link in my answer.

Comment: All yours, thanks for helping out here & have a good Sunday! :-)

Comment: You too! Thanks for the rep. I can’t thank you enough for 500 rep! Now to give back by going through the review queues!

Answer (score -1):

3 years later and here we go....

That concept from app engine is grouping by long running operations

You just need to specify the paramether `operation` in the api call with the object `LogentryOperation`

Here is the reference for this object

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry#LogEntryOperation