# How do I nest app logs in request log and also tag it with an operation id?

Tags: google-app-engine, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

When I use Google App Engine, I can:

- (A) nest app logs (e.g. the info log below)
- (B) see the summary of a request log in the top "collapsed" row
- (C) get tags with an operation id that I can click to easily filter the log stream by

[image: optimal gae log example]

Is it possible to accomplish the same thing via the Stackdriver Logging API?

I understand I can achieve (A) via [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/service/appengine-logs#linking_application_logs_and_requests).

I can achieve (B) by either:

- (i) adding the data to the `httpRequest`
- (ii) adding it to `jsonPayload` and following [this Googler's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36883027/logs-are-not-nested-under-requests-in-flexible-vm/36921823#36921823) to reverse engineer what GAE does.

However, if I choose (i), the operation-id tags (C) no longer appear and if I do the latter, then (A) app log nesting stops working.